# Show browser address bar on android browser

Tags: android, url, jquery-mobile, tablet

Testing jquery mobile web app on samsung galaxy 10.1. 
Is there a way to always show the url of the browser?... or is there a javascript code to show the browser url on a particular event,,,

```
$('.selector').live('click', function(){
   // show brwoser url..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "URL Bar" at the top of the document cannot be programmatically displayed. You can however use the JavaScript location object to create an Address Bar of your own that you could use in your layout.

`window.location.href` displays the whole URL, here is some documentation for ya: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp.

Comment: well, here is the issue which i am trying to resolve.. I am using signature pad (j bradley) and the android screen flickers when user signs. That only happens when the browser url is hidden (looks like the browser is trying to open up the url bar abut snaps back..). So my short term solution was to always have the url visible when the user opens up the dialog to sign...